# Android Studio: Add a button below a gridview adapter

Tags: android, button, adapter

I'm trying to write a small memory game as a tiny xmas gift for my nieces. I used a ImageAdapter for a gridview to display the images of each card. I don't know how to add a button below the gridview (or even initialize an alert).

**Edit: this was solved by the comment of Selvin. I thought I need a special treatment because of the adapter but actually all that was needed was a modification of the ViewGroup of the Adapter.**

Things I tried:

- add a button in the XML, caused an error (multiple root tags)
- looked into dynamically created buttons, couldn't get it work
- tried to use existing alert dialogs - crashed the app on the .show method for the builder

The entire project would be on github as well (public) if that helps.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="[...].MainActivity"/>
```

Java (I believe only this is important):

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,cards));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
    if(v.getTag()!="revealed") { 
    //[...] some if condition that determine when it's won and from there I would like to dynamically create a button or an alert
```

I initially wanted to use a custom class for the cards but honestly I couldn't get it to work with the adapter so now the adapter simply takes image resource IDs. I've got the main game working but I would like to add a button at the bottom of the activity that allows to replay the game. At this point I believe that I could remove the adapter and run it with a regular GridView but I would prefer to learn how to add a button or alert while using an adapter so that I know how to use it for future projects.

Comment: You didn't tried obvious solution ...  any ViewGroup as container which would holds both GridView and Button ... `<ViewGroupProllySomeXXXLayout><Widget1/><Widge2/><Widget2/></ViewGroupProllySomeXXXLayout>`

Comment: I was blind but now I see - thanks!